# Inserting a record to mysql using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to use a cloned div that contains a form to insert a record to the database using this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("<div class='newclone' id='xxx'><article><form method='post' id='aj'><input type='checkbox'><label>Firstname</label><input type='text' value='' name='firstname'><label>Secondname</label><input type='text' value='' name='secondname'><label>City</label><input type='text' value='' name='city'><input type='hidden' value='4'></article><input type='submit' value='insert' class='one'><button class='two'>Delete</button><button class='three'>Cancel</button></form></div>").appendTo('.clone-container');
    }); 

    $('.one').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: $("#aj").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert('Inserted!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the php file

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("clone", $con);

$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$secondname=$_POST['secondname'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO clone(firstname,secondname,city) VALUES ('$firstname','$secondname','$city')");
```

edit

the problem is that there seem to be nothing posted

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ this is the main problem ;)

Comment: StackOverflow isn't "here's my code, fix it".  What is your code doing?  What errors are you getting?  Have you tried debugging it yourself?

Comment: Are you seriously adding the form to your page like that?

Comment: I guess value="" is the problem

Comment: Some people are beginners. Maybe this person is 13 years old for all you know. How about teaching this person how to solve a problem (problem-solving is a skill) instead of just ripping on their crappy code and problem-solving skills?

Comment: @JasonSwett: Because he never said what was was wrong, just "here's some code, it doesn't work".  If he had originally said what wasn't working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test each part separately. Is the Ajax request sending the right data? Is the PHP script even getting the data? (Try `echo <pre>;print_r($_POST);exit;`.) Is your `INSERT` query being formulated correctly? Was it successful?

You don't yet know exactly what your problem is. First figure out what the problem is. Then it will probably be easy to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Also, as a separate issue, you should learn about database input sanitation. It's important.

Comment: Zsanks Jason for zse kind words.I had $('.one').live("click",function() commented out so i panicked a little but its now working.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `$('.one')` to the DOM only after `$("#button")` is clicked on.  So, when `$('.one').click(` is ran, `$('.one')` doesn't exist yet, so the event isn't bound.

You need to use a delegated (or "live") event.

```
$(document).on('click', '.one', function(){
    // Click handler here
});
```